# Does updating a table with same values increase the transaction log file size?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

Or does a transaction log contain only differences?

Are there differences in the log file between these two scripts:

```
DECLARE @f1 INT ,
    @f2 INT 

CREATE TABLE #t ( int F1, int f2 )
UPDATE  #t
SET     f1 = ISNULL(@f1, f1) ,
        f2 = ISNULL(@f2, f2)

--or
IF @f1 IS NOT NULL
    UPDATE  #t
    SET     f1 = ISNULL(@f1, f1)  

IF @f2 IS NOT NULL
    UPDATE  #t
    SET     f2 = ISNULL(@f2, f2)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "yes" for SQL Server, but some SQL Server guru should give the definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if the update is part of the clustered key.

Have a read of this [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20180406220621/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx) titled "The impact of non-updating updates" which discusses this issue.

> *Summary*
>
> SQL Server contains a number of optimisations to avoid unnecessary logging or page flushing when processing an UPDATE
>   operation that will not result in any change to the persistent
>   database.
>
> - Non-updating updates to a clustered table generally avoid extra logging and page flushing, unless a column that forms (part of) the
>     cluster key is affected by the update operation.
> - If any part of the cluster key is ‘updated’ to the same value, the operation is logged as if data had changed, and the affected pages are
>     marked as dirty in the buffer pool.  This is a consequence of the
>     conversion of the UPDATE to a delete-then-insert operation.
> - Heap tables behave the same as clustered tables, except they do not have a cluster key to cause any extra logging or page flushing.  This
>     remains the case even where a non-clustered primary key exists on the
>     heap.  Non-updating updates to a heap therefore generally avoid the
>     extra logging and flushing (but see below).
> - Both heaps and clustered tables will suffer the extra logging and flushing for any row where a LOB column containing more than 8000
>     bytes of data is updated to the same value using any syntax other than
>     ‘SET column_name = column_name’.
>
>   - Simply enabling either type of row versioning isolation level on a database always causes the extra logging and flushing.  This occurs
>       regardless of the isolation level in effect for the update
>       transaction.